# npm mssql prepared statement vs query

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am curious what the difference is between queries and prepared statements in [npm mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssq).

They look the same to me, as most importantly they both sanitize the input.

The query looks simpler to write, but what do I not know? Why use the one over the other?

**Query**

```js
const sql = require('mssql')

(async function () {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config)
        let result = await pool.request()
            .input('input_parameter', sql.Int, value)
            .query('select * from mytable where id = @input_parameter')

        console.dir(result)

    } catch (err) {
        // ... error checks
    }
})()
```

**Prepared statement**

```js
const ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(/* [pool] */)
ps.input('param', sql.Int)
ps.prepare('select @param as value', err => {
    // ... error checks

    ps.execute({param: 12345}, (err, result) => {
        // ... error checks

        // release the connection after queries are executed
        ps.unprepare(err => {
            // ... error checks

        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Any finding for this question @ivan

Comment: Nope. I just use the first one, as it's simpler.

Answer (score 0):

For a one time select, there is little benefit from using a prepared statement vs a query with bound parameters.  However, if you are running a query many times, like updated thousands of rows, preparing that statement outside a loop and running it inside the loop can give a pretty large performance boost.